# How do I sort variables values while keeping track of the variables names?

Tags: javascript

I have 7 variables: rodeo, saya, balthazar, mistral, luna, calypso and kiara. Each of them stores a value resulting from calculations in the initial part of my program.

What I want is to sort these variables based on the value they hold while keeping track of the names of the variables.

I'm wrting this code trying to build a website for my 11 years old daughter on Wix.

```
var points = [rodeo, mistral, calypso, kiara, balthazar, saya, luna];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});   
console.log(points)
```

With this code, I get:
0: 2
1: 2
2: 2
3: 2
4: 3
5: 3
6: 4

Which is the good ranking but I don't know which value belongs to which variable... That's my problem...

Comment: So if you have 4 variables with a value of 2, how will you know which is which? Why do you care?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `array` of `Object` for this purpose.You can use `find()` to get the value of name.

```js
var points = [{name:"rodeo",value:3}, {name:"mistral",value:3},{name:"calypso",value:1}, {name:"kiara",value:6}, {name:"balthazar",value:3}, {name:"saya",value:2}, {name:"luna",value:4}];
points = points.sort((a,b) => a.value - b.value);
console.log(points)
console.log("value of kiara = " + points.find(({name}) => name === "kiara").value)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be to store your variables as objects within your array and then sort the values of those objects. This way you can see which "variable" is associated with what value.

See example below:

```js
var rodeo = 3;
var mistral = 2;
var calypso = 2;
var kiara = 2;
var balthazar = 2;
var saya = 4;
var luna = 3;
var points = [{rodeo}, {mistral}, {calypso}, {kiara}, {balthazar}, {saya}, {luna}],

result = points.sort(function(a, b){return Object.values(a)[0]-Object.values(b)[0]});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: And how does the OP use the variable "name" to access the object property, or *vice versa*?

Comment: @RobG I was under the impression that they just wanted to see which variable belongs to which score. (eg so they can print out a scoreboard), not to access the points via the variable name - using the variable name wouldn't be needed as the value associated with it is stored in the value itself